# Is it possible to load data from flat file and dump in to hibernate second level cache?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, file, plugins

below is my query:

Currently we are reading data from DB(Oracle) using Hibernate and ehcache second level cache for performance of the application.

my New Requirement: instead of hitting DB(oracle) ,I need to read data from Flat file and same data has to map( Hibernate second level cache), so that i can reuse my whole application again. just changing dialect to support reading from file.

do we have any hibernate or other third party Plugins to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438/using-hibernate-to-work-with-text-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require a hibernate dialect that could read the format of your file, which doesn't exist.  You could write your own dialect, but not sure that's an option.

Another approach might be to use in in-memory data provider, load the data there, and run, something like HSQL.